# TEXT field in MySqli shows "undefined" when we try to add data

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to insert data into "studentremark" table.  It has a field with TEXT data type.  But when I insert data into that field the content shows "undefined".  Here is the code" I'm using ajax for page processing.

```
$faculty=$_REQUEST['faculty'];
$stcode=$_REQUEST['stcode'];
$rem=$_REQUEST['rem'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "INSERT INTO studentremark (STCODE, TID, rdate, remarks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('siss',$stcode, $faculty, $date, $rem);
if(!$query->execute())
{
    echo("Some unknown error occurs, Item cannot be added.");
}
else
{
    echo("Student remarks added successfully !!");
}
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Get the *actual* errors and go from there. Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: @Prasanth check your variables($faculty,$stcode$ref) with `isset()` before assign

Comment: which column in the table has the datatype TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO studentremark (STCODE, TID, rdate, remarks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('siss',$stcode, $faculty, $date, $rem);

    $faculty=$_REQUEST['faculty'];
    $stcode=$_REQUEST['stcode'];
    $rem=$_REQUEST['rem'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    if(!$query->execute()) {
        echo("Some unknown error occurs, Item cannot be added.");
    } else {
        echo("Student remarks added successfully !!");
    }
```

Check this [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

look at the your code you have four placeholders but trying to bind five values, fix that, try using my code below

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO studentremark (STCODE, TID, rdate, remarks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('siss',$stcode, $date, $rem); // looking at columns i felt $faculty was extra so i removed it.
```

Then for seeing the exact error message use the below procedure to execute the query

```
$query->execute() or die(mysqli_error());
```